# varnish - little delay after 5 seconds idle

Tags: server, varnish, hhvm

I installed varnish on a hello world application, along with nginx, hhvm and mongodb.

The only things that bugges me is that the first time when I access the url I get around 125 ms response time and if I refresh the website again within the next 5 seconds I get around 60-70 ms.

If I wait more than 5 seconds to refresh I get again around 125 ms, but if I remove varnish and relay only on nginx, I get 60-70 ms all the time.

Any thoughts why this is happenig? I am using Varnish 4.0.3

Comment: Not directly related, by why not use https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-fastcgi-caching-with-nginx-on-your-vps instead? It is essentially the same thing, but without another failure point...

Comment: Can I use it with HHVM? since I am not using php FPM

Comment: I am 99% you can, haven't tried myself, but I don't think it really matters at this point. Both use FastCGI, and neither HHVM nor PHP-FPM even do anything at that point.